# Three.js rendering and bootstrap grids

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, three.js

I am playing around with three.js and bootstrap. But, when using the bootstrap grids, my cube gets flattened like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2G4D.jpg

Though when resizing the window, it works fine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E09BL.jpg

I have tried to fix this in css, but it didn't work:

**CSS**

```
@media(min-width:768px) { 

canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 33% !important;
}
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Any ideas?

***EDIT:***

I also tried to work with the js code, but also no results:

**JS:**

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.getElementById('render').appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    render();
}

function onWindowResize() {

if (window.matchMedia('(min-width:768px)').matches) {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight * 0.33);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    render();
}

else {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    render();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is probably that your using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.
Using these is fine is you want your three.js canvas to fill the whole window, but it seems as if you are putting your three.js canvas inside of a div.
Instead of using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, you probably want to use the width and height of the container div.

You probably want to use something like `document.getElementById('myDiv').style.height` or `document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight` instead.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "can't get the style into the javascript"

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate your help! Got a great solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38789139/css-how-to-set-the-width-and-height-dependent-on-the-screen-window-size) ;)

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me with bootstrap , css:

```
#webgl_container{
  width:100%;
  min-width:300px;
  height:640px;
  margin:auto;
}

#webglworld{
  min-width:400px;
  width:100%;
  height:600px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id= "webgl_container" class="row">
 <div id="webglworld">
 </div>
<div>
```

Js :

```
function init() {
    scale = 10;
    WEBGL_ID = "webglworld";
    webgl_div= document.getElementById(WEBGL_ID);
    set_height_and_width();
    aspectRatio = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
....
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    webgl_div.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
....}

function set_height_and_width(){
    var dimensions = webgl_div.getBoundingClientRect();
    HEIGHT = dimensions.height;
    WIDTH = dimensions.width;
    ......}

function onWindowResize() {
    set_height_and_width();
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT; ......
```